# Django v2+ how to properly use AppConfig for reusable apps

Tags: python, django, django-templates

After Django's 8 part tutorial there is an additional "[Advanced Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/#)" which gives a quick-start like approach into python packaging. Namely, moving the Django tutorial app "polls" outside of a Django project and preparing it to be pushed to PyPi.

While this information is useful and covers a bit more ground that Python's own packaging tutorial (e.g. the MANIFEST file to include static / template resources).  It doesn't quite explain how to make an app reusable in the sense of configurable options.

For example, if the app has a runtime dependency variable `my_bool`, how one would open up setting this option for their reusable app.

My first instinct was [AppConfig](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig). However, subclassing `AppConfig` for this purpose isn't explained in the documentation.

One could assume that all the options / settable variables come from the main `settings.py` file and set defaults if not there... but that also isn't explicitly stated or recommended in any of the Django docs that I have read thus far.

For a reusable application I am making, I would like the user to be able to augment the app with their own data files.

Thus they would need to supply these files in a directory somewhere (with a specified, designated structure) and then tell my app where they are e.g. `MY_APP_DATA_DIR="os.path.join(BASE_DIR, <location>)"`.

Where would such variables go in a reusable Django app?

Would one use a dependency like `python-decouple` to grab these values?

Comment: Why wouldn't the settings just go in the settings.py?

Comment: @DanielRoseman perhaps there is a lot, or there is post-processing of the setting values required. I only pointed out that guidance of where to put setting values for a reusable app is not specified.